# Microsoft Query Group / Partition By

Tags: sql, excel, vba

Suppose I have the following data in a DB I am trying to query via Microsoft Query in Excel:

```
Col_A:     Col_B:     Col_C:    Col_D:    Date1:     Date2:
a1         b1         c1        d1        Dt1_1      Dt2_1
a1         b2         c2        d2        Dt1_1      Dt2_2
a1         b3         c3        d3        Dt1_1      Dt2_3
a1         b4         c4        d4        Dt1_2      Dt2_4
a1         b5         c5        d5        Dt1_2      Dt2_5
```

And, in terms of dates, assume, for example, "_1" < "_2".
So, what I want is, for each value in `Col_A`, to get one row for each `Date1` for the earliest `Date2`.

So, given this data, I'd want to get back:

```
Col_A:     Col_B:     Col_C:    Col_D:    Date1:     Date2:
a1         b1         c1        d1        Dt1_1      Dt2_1
a1         b4         c4        d4        Dt1_2      Dt2_4
```

In other words, since `Date1` changed, we get the data for the earliest `Date2`.
I hope that makes sense.

In MySQL, I believe the query would look like:

```
SELECT Col_A, Col_B, Col_C, Col_D, Date1, Date2
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY Col_A, Date1, Date2
GROUP BY Col_A, Date1, Date2
```

Or something like:

```
SELECT Col_A, Col_B, Col_C, Col_D, Date1, Date2,
       RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Col_A, Date1 ORDER BY Date2) as RN
FROM MyTable
WHERE RN = 1
ORDER BY Col_A, Date1, Date2
```

... I know this won't work, but the logic is pretty much what I'm looking for...

But I have no clue how to do this in Microsoft Query.

I hope this makes sense!!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Query does not give you a lot of options, so your best best is to create this as a view in the database.  Here is MSSQL SQL to set it up:

```
CREATE VIEW MyView AS
WITH M_CTE(M_COL_A, M_Date1, M_Date2)
AS(
  SELECT A.[Col_A]
      ,A.[Date1]
      ,MIN(A.[Date2]) AS Date2
  FROM [Sheet1] A
  GROUP BY A.[Col_A]
  ,A.[Date1])
SELECT B.* FROM [Sheet1] B
INNER JOIN M_CTE
ON B.Col_A = M_COL_A
AND B.Date1 = M_Date1
AND B.Date2 = M_Date2
```

And then you can connect to the view quite easily with MS Query in Excel for example.

Comment: This didn't end up working for me due to it being such an old DB structure, but this was a smart idea...